# Creating the mean average of every nth object in a specific column of a dataframe

Tags: r, average

I am trying to average every n-th object of a specific column in a dataframe using the following code. I understand that using the for-loop is computationally inefficient. This is why I would like to ask whether there is a more efficient way to create the average of every n-th row? My data looks a little bit like this.

```
set.seed(6218)
n <- 8760
s1 <- sample(30000:70000, n)
s2 <- sample(0:10000, n)
inDf <- cbind(s1, s2)
```

EDIT:

I call h_average like this:
h_average(inDf, 24, 1, 1)
This would mean that I average every first point of "every" 24 point subset. So the points 1, 25, 49, 73,... Also I only do this for the first column.

Thanks in advance,
BenR

```
#' h_average
#' 
#' Computing the average of every first, second, third, ... hour of the day/week
#' 
#' @param data merged data
#' @param tstep hour-step representing the number of hours for a day/week
#' @param h hour, which should be averaged. Should be between 1 - 24/1 - 168.
#' @param x column number
#' @return mean average of the specific hour
h_average <- function(data, tstep, h, x) {
  sum_1 <- 0
  sum_2 <- 0
  mean  <- 0

  for (i in seq(h, nrow(data), tstep)){
    if(data[i,x]){
      sum_1 <- sum_1 + 1
      sum_2 <- sum_2 + data[i,x]
    }
  }
  mean <- sum_2/sum_1
  return(mean)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a combination of `rowMeans` and subsetting. So something like:

```
n = 5
rowMeans(data[seq(1, nrow(data), n),])
```

Alternatively, you could use `apply`

```
## rowMeans is better, but 
## if you wanted to calculate the median (say)
## Just change mean to median below
apply(data[seq(1, nrow(data), n),], 1, mean)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this tonight! Also, I forgot to add that I would like to compute the mean of every n-th entry of a column... I just colMeans in that case?!

Comment: @BenR you could also make group indicators and then use `by`, `ave`, `aggregate`, `plyr::ddply`, etc

Comment: Hi I have a 7700 x 94 Dataframe with Column and row names. I want a 1100 x 94 dataframe where the 1100 new numbers are 7 day averages of the original 7700. How to do?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to reproduce `h_average` but without the loop then

**1) colMeans**  Try this:

```
# assume inDf and h_average as defined in the question

tstep <- 24
h <- x <- 1

h_average(inDf, tstep, h, x)
##       s1 
## 49299.09 

# same but without loop
colMeans(inDf[seq(h, nrow(inDf), tstep), x, drop = FALSE])
##       s1 
## 49299.09
```

This also works if `x` is a vector of column numbers, e.g. `x = 1:2`.

**1a)** This variation works too:

```
colMeans(inDf[seq_len(tstep) == h, x, drop = FALSE])
```

**2) aggregate** Another possibility is this:

```
aggregate(DF[x], list(h = gl(tstep, 1, nrow(inDf))), mean)[h, ]
```

which has the advantage that both `x` and `h` may be vectors, e.g.

```
x <- 1:2
h <- 1:3

DF <- as.data.frame(inDF)
aggregate(DF[x], list(h = gl(tstep, 1, nrow(inDf))), mean)[h, ]
##   h       s1       s2
## 1 1 49299.09 4964.277
## 2 2 49661.34 5177.910
## 3 3 49876.77 4946.447
```

To get all `h` then use `h <- 1:tstep` or just omit `[h, ]`.

**Note:** `InDf` as defined in the question is a matrix and not a data frame as its name seems to suggest.

**Update** Some improvements in (1) and added (1a) and (2).

Comment: Thank you really much for your reply! Your absolutely right about inDf. It is coerced in my code...

Comment: Hi I have a 7700 x 94 Dataframe with Column and row names. I want a 1100 x 94 dataframe where the 1100 new numbers are 7 day averages of the original 7700. Can I use this for that?